# Deleting the MySQL database

Tags: sql

My SQL file has been deleted and I don't have a backup of it, if my WP file exists, how can I create a database for it?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You can create a fresh database by running the WordPress install, but it won't contain any of your content. That's all gone if you didn't have a backup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a full backup version that when I do all the steps to restore, it only brings up the initial default format, otherwise all the information is available in the WordPress file.

Comment: That's confusing, because you said, "*My SQL file has been deleted and I don't have a backup of it*", then you said, "*I have a full backup version*". So, do you, or do you *not*, have a backup of the SQL file? And, "*when I do all the steps to restore, it only brings up the initial default format*", what steps and what do you mean by "default format"? Have you checked [this](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/restoring-your-database-from-backup/)?

Comment: After a lot of searching in Windows, I noticed a full backup file that I took on 1/31/2023.
From this full backup file, I inserted the parts of the WordPress and SQL files, and I realized that it only shows the purchased template, which is Woodmart, in raw form, and does not show any of the information stored in the public HTML file. does not give
It does not show any of the settings made for the header and products section, and the Woodmart template comes up without any settings.
I hope I have fully explained

Comment: If I refer to the public HTML file, all product photos and information are available

Comment: If the full backup was a complete backup of your WordPress site (i.e. it includes the SQL file and other files like images, plugins and themes), then you could try restoring the entire backup to a staging site, then push it to your production site once everything is confirmed working and looking as expected. Or if you know how (e.g. what plugin/tool) you used to create the backup file, then maybe you can restore it using the same plugin/tool. Check [this article](https://jetpack.com/blog/how-to-restore-a-wordpress-website-from-a-backup/) for more information and other options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, in the full backup file, it seems that the SQL file has a problem, and no matter what I did, the site could not be loaded with my information, and I started building the site again.